# Protected methods can be called on the object of subclass without overriding. Why it's different for clone method in java.lang.Object?

Tags: java, overriding, clone, subclass, protected

If I have a class A

```
    public class A {
        protected void show() {
        }
    }
```

Another class B

```
    public class B extends A {
    }
```

Driver class:

```
    public class Driver {
          public static void main(String[] args) {
                  B b = new B();
                  b.show();
          }
    }
```

This thing works fine. But why is it different for clone method in Object class? If I don't override the clone method with a public modifier I get an error like: "clone has protected access in Object". We know Object is by default parent of all classes. So, this should also work the same as for the classes Driver, A and B. Why is it different?

Comment: Are `Driver` and `A` in the same package?

Comment: If `A`, `B` and `Driver` all resides in different packages, then `b.show()` won't compile too. I guess that in your example `A` and `Driver` are in the same package, thus there is no error.

Comment: Can you provide packages of the classes?

Answer (score -1):

From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone())

the `clone()` method in a class must respect some conventions :

> By convention, the returned object should be obtained by calling
>   super.clone. If a class and all of its superclasses (except Object)
>   obey this convention, it will be the case that x.clone().getClass() ==
>   x.getClass().
>
> By convention, the object returned by this method should be
>   independent of this object (which is being cloned). To achieve this
>   independence, it may be necessary to modify one or more fields of the
>   object returned by super.clone before returning it. Typically, this
>   means copying any mutable objects that comprise the internal "deep
>   structure" of the object being cloned and replacing the references to
>   these objects with references to the copies. If a class contains only
>   primitive fields or references to immutable objects, then it is
>   usually the case that no fields in the object returned by super.clone
>   need to be modified.
>
> The method clone for class Object performs a specific cloning
>   operation. First, if the class of this object does not implement the
>   interface Cloneable, then a CloneNotSupportedException is thrown. Note
>   that all arrays are considered to implement the interface Cloneable
>   and that the return type of the clone method of an array type T[] is
>   T[] where T is any reference or primitive type. Otherwise, this method
>   creates a new instance of the class of this object and initializes all
>   its fields with exactly the contents of the corresponding fields of
>   this object, as if by assignment; the contents of the fields are not
>   themselves cloned. Thus, this method performs a "shallow copy" of this
>   object, not a "deep copy" operation.
>
> The class Object does not itself implement the interface Cloneable, so
>   calling the clone method on an object whose class is Object will
>   result in throwing an exception at run time.

It means that either you have to override the clone() method and implements `Cloneable` OR use clone() directly with handling of a thrown `CloneNotSupportedException`